# Finding implementations of an interface in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking at the following method.

```
public void setRecordValidator(Validator recordValidator) {
    this.recordValidator = recordValidator;
}
```

In this case class Validator is an interface. I'm not sure what kind of object to pass on to the method since I'm not sure what classes actually implement Validator.

The question is how can I view classes that implement Validator in Eclipse?

Comment: `Ctrl + G` ? shortcut

Comment: Select Validator, right-click, choose "Open Type Hierarchy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to get this information, here are some of them:

Right click on the name of the interface and select `Open Type Hierarchy` (the shortcut for this is `F4` by default).

Alternatively, you could right click it and choose `References > Hierarchy` instead.

`CTRL+T` will give you a Javadoc-style popup with the type hierarchy inside.

There are plenty of other ways to do this, so pick your poison really.

Answer (score 4):

Click on `Validator` somewhere in the code and press Ctrl+T - this will open the Type Hierarchy popup.

Answer (score 3):

Rightclick on Validator -> Declarations -> Project

Rightclick on Validator in the search result -> Implementations -> Project

Answer (score 2):

Open the interface then **select *search* -> *implementers*-> Select *Project***

[image]

Or Select the interface name then ctrl + T

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select `Validator` in

```
 public void setRecordValidator(Validator recordValidator) {
    this.recordValidator = recordValidator;
 }
```

and press F4 key.